# Show that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire. Suppose $f(z+1)=f(z)=f(z+i)$ for all complex number $z$. Show that $f$ is a constant. 
Here I tried to use Liouville Theorem.(i.e. If f is entire and bounded, then f must be constant.). But how can I show whether it is bounded?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161732/an-elliptic-function-can-not-be-holomorphic-analytic

Comment: @Henry W.. Ohh I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for all $z$ we find $w$ with $0\le \Re w\le1$ and $0\le \Im w\le 1$ and $f(z)=f(w)$, and that $f$ is bounded on that square.